# Putty: Local port 80 forwarding to localhost:80 failed: Network error: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, windows-10, putty

In putty, I have the following:

- **Session**

  - hostname:username@azurecontainsersvc_mgmt.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
  - port: 2200
- **Connection>SSH>Tunnels** L80 localhost:80
- **Connection>SSH>Auth Private key:** my_public_key.ppk

Ans when I connect, it asks me for my password, everything looks great, but I get access denied.  I have tried running as admin with the same results.

> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Connecting to [IP_Address] port 2200
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.69
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2
>   Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Using SSH protocol version 2
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and
>   hash SHA-256
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host
>   keys, but we don't know any of them
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Host key fingerprint is:
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   ssh-ed25519 256 [Fingerprint]
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server
>   encryption
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC
>   algorithm
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client
>   encryption
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC
>   algorithm
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Reading key file "C:\path_to_certs\privatekey.ppk"
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Offered public key
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Offer of public key accepted
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Sent public key signature
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Access granted
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Opening session as main channel
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Opened main channel
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Local port 80 forwarding to localhost:80 failed:
>   Network error: Permission denied
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Started a shell/command

Any ideas?  I am lost - thank you!

Not sure if it matters, but I am trying to connect to a DC/OS cluster on Azure: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect

Comment: is `AllowTcpForwarding` set to `yes` in the sshd config of your server?

Comment: we have one machine in the office that can connect via Putty to the server, so I assume that is not the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That problems can have different origins:

1. tcp port 80 is already in use by another program. Check if you have a local web server running.
2. You don't have sufficient privileges to open port 80. Listening to ports under 1024 needs administrator privileges.
3. port forwarding is not permitted on the server side (`AllowTcpForwarding no` in `sshd_config`). If you can't change sshd_config on the server, then it just won't be possible to forward ports.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have an open session on port 80 or check that you are running putty as an admin. Win 10 is picky.

Comment: I have no open Putty sessions, is there something else I should check?

Comment: And I am running Putty as admin